# Updating virtual environment from yml file

Tags: linux, git, flask, hosting, python-venv

I have a flask application which is being hosted inside a linux container on a server.

I have cloned the repository on my laptop for development and want to be able to update the application on my personal PC an push the changes to the container.

This is set up but struggling to know how to update the virtual environment.

**How do you update a virtual environment from a yml file and vice versa?**

I have a venv which I activate for development. I need to be able to update the yml file of the cloned repository with all new packages installed in this venv.

Once this is done I commit the changes to the linux container.

I then need to take this newly updated yml file and update the venv inside the container.

Anyone have an idea on how to navigate this process?

Comment: Are you using an online hosting service? If so, which one? Or are you hosting this yourself? We need to know more about how this is hosted to be able to answer the question.

Comment: It is hosted on our work sever.

I think we are using gunicorn for the hosting. 

Sorry I am not in IT. Just trying to figure this process out. Hope that answered your question

Comment: Yes, it clarifies things. With a cloud service, the answer would be very different, but here you need to know how to update things yourself on your own self-hosted container.